# Отображение блоков в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css, браузер

Вот [макет](https://cdn.rawgit.com/agafron/landing-css-modest/070a7e42/index.html), в Firefox при изменении размера колесиком, первый блок после `header`(class welcome) отображается не так как в Chrome.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Не так - это как?

Comment: если в ФФ увеличивать размер, то появляется разрыв между хидер и welcome

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_2325916_29352350.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `-webkit-background-size: 100%;` сделайте `-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;` или со значением 100% 100%. Если я не ошибаюсь, есть только `-webkit-background-size`, а у вас прописано `-о-background-size`, `-moz-background-size`. [Здесь](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#backgrounds), вы можете подробно почитать про `background`.

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста еще один момент, в секции #team в FF  hover в на первых 2-х картинках не работает, хотя стиль везде один, если поставить 3-ю или 4-ю картинку на их места, то все работает, в чем может быть косяк? http://pixs.ru/showimage/Peek201802_2724494_29360989.gif

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы имеете введу эту полоску, то все дело в свойстве "background-size": 100%; Все дело в том что в хроме backround-size определяется как 100% 100%, в мозилле как 100% auto; Вам нужно всего лишь указать backround-size: 100% 100%;

#### p.s

Прочитайте по разный значения Background size, скорее всего вам нужно значение "cover".

Comment: Комментарий относится к блокe с айдишником "banner"